# Browser Ghost Image Briefly Appears

Tags: google-chrome, web-browser

I am regularly seeing the top edge of another Chrome browser window in the bottom right of my Macbook Air screen (OS 10.11.6). I can't see enough of the window to view the contents, but it only last about 2 seconds, and then whooshes off the screen. It often happens when I open a new tab or window while using Chrome.

Has anyone else experienced this? I don't have a screen shot because it happens so quickly.

Comment: Have you ever connected an external monitor to your MBA at any time?

Comment: Never, only a portable CD player, a Kindle (does that count as a monitor?)...

Comment: My idea was that you'd set some Chrome window to open on another monitor that is now disconnected. • What happens if you run Chrome when the MBA is disconnected from a network (either wired or wireless)? • Do you have a default page that opens when you run Chrome? (Preferences > On startup > Open a specific page or set of pages) Perhaps there is odd page stuck in there from the past.